# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath get instance of selected section

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Is there a way to get the instance of the section in which a row was selected? It is possible to get the index of the section, the index of the selected cell, the instance of the selected cell..but the instance of this section?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow // index path of selected cell

    let headerCellIndex = indexPath!.section // index of selected section
    let headerCellName = ????? // instance of selected section

    let cellIndex = indexPath!.row // index of selected cell
    let cellName = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) //  instance of selected cell
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: How you insert the name of your section when the tableview load?

Comment: `String(content[section].sectionName)`

This would also work in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`-method..But isn't there a way to get the name of the section somehow similar to how you get the name of the selected cell?

Comment: is the content an array/ object?

Comment: Why dont you try when in didSelectRow... `var secName = content[indexPath.section].sectionName`

Comment: yes this works..but I was wondering if there is no way similar to how one get the name of the selected cell..

Comment: you aren't getting the 'name' of the cell, you're getting the cell instance... the suggestion from @lee is the correct solution, not querying the view for the name

Comment: yes you are right.. I get the name with `textLabel.text` of the instance..do you know how to get the instance of the section?

Comment: what do you mean by name of selected cell? you should be have any array before table load right?

Comment: =) sorry I confused you.. @Wain was right: I am not getting the name but the instance of cell.. so the question would be "how to get the instance of the section in which the selected cell is"..

Comment: there is no section instance, and you should not get label text from the cell - always get the data from your data model, only get the cell instance so you can update it

Comment: okei thanks that's the answer I was looking for.. =)

Answer (score 13):

This always worked well for me. I always unwrap it as well optionally to the class I assigned to it just to make sure I have the right type of cell. In this example I have MyTableViewCell but it can of course be anything.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {
         print(cell.label.text!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With function DidSelectRows you can use a switch like this (Ex. 3 Sections, variable Rows)

```
switch indexPath.section {
case 0:
   switch indexPath.row {
      case 0:
      Action to do with first cell (ex. performSegue(withIdentifier: "", sender: nil)
      case 1:
      Action to do with second cell
      default:
         break
      }
case 1:
   Things you want to do in the second section
case 2:
   Things you want to do in the third section
default:
break
}
```

Comment: Sections come from web services dynamically, how can i get the indexpath.

Answer (score -1):

or Swift 3.0, use

> override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt 
>   indexPath: IndexPath){
>
> //your code...
>
> }